# Python Time Delta time data does not match format error, can't find my mistake

Tags: python, datetime

```
time data '2015-07-30 20:32:01.521834' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S.%f'
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: You're missing the dash “-” between date and time.

Comment: @mknecht looks like I actually needed not to have it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>>import datetime
>>>datetime.datetime.strptime('2015-07-30 20:32:01.521834', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
>>>datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 30, 20, 32, 1, 521834)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a redundant dash `-` between the date and the time

Change:

```
'%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S.%f'
```

to:

```
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
```